# I want to show my model popup subscription page only on home page

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, model, popup

I have eCommerce website on which i made an popup model for subscription i want to show that popup only on homepage right now it's showing on all pages of website how can i do that ??

See my code below...

```
    <!-- Modal -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#modal-subscription").modal('show');
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if you are in your home URL by an if condition on `window.location.href`

```
 <!-- Modal -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if (window.location.href === "YOUR HOMEPAGE URL") {
            $("#modal-subscription").modal('show');
        }
    });
</script>
```

More on location object here at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location).

Comment: that's perfectly worked for me thanks a lot bro ... Problem Solved